# Login into external Api and Post JSON to it

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a post request to an external api that requires a username and password to be sent as headers. Currently the username and password are hardcoded. I want anyone to be able to login (with a account) and post the the api. I was wondering if there is a way to enable the browser native login prompt and use it for the api? Below is the code with the hardcoded username and password

```
public class RestService {
    String Username="admin";
    String Password="pass";

  public String createPost() throws AuthenticateException,ClientHandlerException {

String url = "https://someapi.net/rest/api/2/issue/";

Client client = Client.create ();

client.addFilter (new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(Username, Password));
WebResource webResource= client.resource(url);
//--INPUT is formatted a bit different In my app but I just can't show it
String input = "{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}"

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class,input);
string output = response.getEntity(String.Class)
```

below is my controller

```
public class IndexController {
@Autowired
private RestService restService;

@GetMapping(value="/run")
public void test1() throws Exception{
restService.CreatePost();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simpler to use Spring REST Client - RestTemplate?
In your case

```
@Service
public class RestService {

  public String createPost() {
    final var restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final var username = "admin";
    final var password = "pass";
    final var url = "https://someapi.net/rest/api/2/issue/";
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
    //header will look like 'Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==' ('username:password' with Base64)
    var fieldsFromInputObject = new FieldsFromInputObject();
    fieldsFromInputObject.setSummary("REST ye merry gentlemen.");
    //here set another fields
    var inputObject = new InputObject();
    inputObject.setFields(fields);
    var request = new HttpEntity<>(inputObject, headers);
    var response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
    //instead object you can use your serialized JSON
    //last parameter determines a class of the response
  }
}
```

About entering user's credentials: it's the very simple task and you can find plenty of links with this the simplest form and method controller which will handle these request parameters:

1. The Controller which contains the method with 2 parameters (of course, POST because GET requests non-secured)
2. Simple web-page with fields (native html, jsp, thymeleaf or others)
3. Configuration for your MVC application

Comment: Java 10 rolled out `var` keyword feature. You can use var keyword if you using Java 10 in your application.